# prettyPhoto not working #prettyPhoto/#/ not generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, prettyphoto

I implemented a link like in the prettyPhoto Documentation, but it is not working

the JavaScript is processed (alert is popping up)
But dependent where the alert is positioned in the function it is working or not.

If the alert is at the beginning prettyPhoto works fine and the URL is generated
If the alert is missing or at the end the URL is pointing to the image and opens the image in fullscreen.

Any idea to get it working without an alert?!

here is the code:

```
function prettyPhoto() {

    //alert("Test"); //beginning pretty photo is working URL appended #prettyPhoto/0/

    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({            
        show_title: true,           
        theme: 'pp_default', 
        social_tools: false
    }); 

    alert("Test Ende"); //at the end prettyPhoto is NOT working URL is changing to the location of the image        
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are calling your function to early, before the HTML elements you’re trying to select even exists. (The alert window “pauses” the script, so that the rest of the document has time to load.) Just place your function call at the bottom of the document or use `$.function()` to call it.